# RISC-V in FPGA's booting is stucked with "Starting kernel..." when i changed the version of linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, fpga, riscv

I tried to implement RISC-V in VC707 boards with vivado-risc-v(https://github.com/eugene-tarassov/vivado-risc-v) within different version of original code.

First of all, I checked it works well when i implement linux kernel version 6.3.12 in master tree.
And i tried to change the linux kernel version to 5.7.1 with below.

1. Change the version of vivado-risc-v
   -> Vivado-risc-v v2.2.0 supported Linux kernel version 5.7.1, So i tried to implement. But it doesn't support newest version of BOOM(Berkely Out Of Order Machine).
2. Build Hardware in Vivado-risc-v's master version, and build OS in Vivado-risc-v's v2.2.0
   -> Newest version doesn't support oldest version of booting(because its system is changed from riscv-pk to BBL)
3. Change Linux-state folder & change patches.
   -> In Github issue, author suggest to change the version of Linux Kernel and change patches in Vivado-risc-v's master version.(https://github.com/eugene-tarassov/vivado-risc-v/issues/179).

It can't build OS image without changing patch, so i replaced the patch files( fpga-axi-eth.c, fpga-axi-sdc.c, linux.config, linux.patch) from master version to v2.2.0.

Its image build works well & I checked it works well in QEMU.

I changed linux.config & linux.patch's code lines like below for checking debugging code.

`CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT=15 CONFIG_CONSOLE_LOGLEVEL_QUIET=15 CONFIG_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL_DEFAULT=7`

But it doesn't show anything else & and stuck in "Starting Kernel..." like image below.
I can't figure out where's the wrong point.
[Stucking Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrWeB.png)

When I stopped auto-boot and check the boards status, it shows what i want to implement.
[CPU INFO & BoardInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDgvZ.png)

In summury, here is my questions.

1. How could i figure out where is the point of stucking problem?
2. How could i fix it?(I never do change any HW sources yet.)
3. I guessed this problem is occured by HW(like bootrom, ethernet, sdc, or etc...), but it cannot solve problem easily by replacing the codes, how could i solve problems?

Thank you for your any advice or supports.

Comment: Typical situation for trying the `earlycon` or `earlyprintk` feature of the Linux kernel. You would need to both (1) enable it in the kernel build, *and* (2) enable it through the kernel command line. If you still get no output, then either (a) `earlycon`/`earlyprintk` wasn't properly built/enabled, or (b) kernel failed so early that nothing was output (rather unlikely), or (c) kernel never executed because kernel image is bad from storage medium or was clobbered in memory.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I tried it by enabling earlycon/earlyprinkt.
But, it doesn't show any message yet.
I think it can't upload linux with Hardware Issue.

Comment: "*it doesn't show any message yet*" -- You need to be positive that `earlycon`/`earlyprintk` was properly built & enabled, or you will be wasting time looking in the wrong places. "*I think it can't upload linux ...*" -- "Upload"??? There's no network transfer going on; don't misuse jargon.  If you're positive that the kernel isn't displaying anything, then you will need to dig into the U-Boot environment and/or boot script, and load the images but not actually boot. Verify that the images are valid/intact, especially the kernel image.